Spring Boot 3.1 + Apache Struts 7.0.0-M8 missing javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
I have here an Application that uses Spring Boot 3.1 and Apache Struts 7.0.0-M8. I just can't get them to run as the Java classloader persistently tries to load the javax. HttpServletRequest instead instead of the Jakarta Servlet.
I debugged the code, upgraded dependencies,
checked for any usages. Multiple times deleted my gradle cache and invalidated my IntelliJ cache.
Where is that call even coming from? The only hunch I have is that none is loaded and it defaults to javax which it can't find. But if that is the case should I make it available on start up in my spring-boot configuration?
What can I do?
Here the Dependency Tree:
annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:3.3.1
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30

bootArchives - Configuration for Spring Boot archive artifacts. (n)
No dependencies

compileClasspath - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
+--- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.1.0
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.1
+--- org.ow2.asm:asm:9.7
+--- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:6.0.0
+--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2
|    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3
+--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:3.0.0
+--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5
|    \--- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-core:4.0.5
|         +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2 (*)
|         +--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3
|         +--- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:4.0.5
|         \--- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:4.1.2
+--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3
+--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.11
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-jcl:6.1.11 -> 6.1.10
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.1
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.3.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.3.1
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.10
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:6.1.10
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.10
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.10 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:6.1.10
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |         \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:1.12.7 -> 1.13.1
|    |    |              \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:1.13.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:3.3.1
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:3.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:3.3.1
|    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.6
|    |    |    |    +--- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.5.6
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.13
|    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:2.23.1
|    |    |    |    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1 -> 2.23.0
|    |    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9 -> 2.0.13
|    |    |    \--- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:2.0.13
|    |    |         \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.13
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1 -> 3.0.0
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    \--- org.yaml:snakeyaml:2.2
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:3.3.1
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:3.3.1 (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.10
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.10 (*)
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    |    |    \--- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:1.12.7 -> 1.13.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.17.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.17.1 (c)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.1
|    |    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:2.17.1
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.17.1
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1 (*)
|    |    \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:2.17.1
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.17.1 (*)
|    |         +--- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.17.1 (*)
|    |         \--- com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:2.17.1 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.3.1
|    |    +--- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1 -> 3.0.0
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.25
|    |    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.25
|    |    \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:10.1.25
|    |         \--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.25
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.10 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:6.1.10
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:6.1.10 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.10 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.10 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-expression:6.1.10 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.10 (*)
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:3.3.1 (*)
+--- org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1
+--- jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:3.0.0
|    +--- jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.0.0 -> 6.1.0
|    \--- jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:5.0.0 -> 6.0.0
+--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:10.1.25
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.25
|    +--- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:10.1.25
|    \--- org.eclipse.jdt:ecj:3.33.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.0
+--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.23.1
|    \--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1 -> 2.23.0
+--- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:7.0.0-M8
|    +--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.33
|    +--- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:3.1.8
|    |    +--- org.checkerframework:checker-qual:3.37.0
|    |    \--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.21.1 -> 2.27.0
|    +--- ognl:ognl:3.3.5
|    |    \--- org.javassist:javassist:3.29.0-GA
|    +--- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.1 -> 2.23.0
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-fileupload2-jakarta-servlet6:2.0.0-M2
|    |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-fileupload2-core:2.0.0-M2
|    |    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.15.1
|    |    \--- commons-io:commons-io:2.15.1
|    +--- commons-io:commons-io:2.15.1
|    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0
|    \--- org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.12.0
|         \--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0
+--- com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-tree-plugin:5.0.4
|    +--- com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-plugin:5.0.4
|    |    +--- org.apache.struts:struts-annotations:1.0.8
|    |    |    \--- org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.31 -> 2.3.33
|    |    +--- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:6.4.0 -> 7.0.0-M8 (*)
|    |    \--- org.apache.struts:struts2-velocity-plugin:6.4.0 -> 7.0.0-M8
|    |         +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.3
|    |         |    +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11 -> 3.14.0
|    |         |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 2.0.13
|    |         +--- org.apache.struts:struts2-velocity-tools-view-jakarta:7.0.0-M8
|    |         \--- org.apache.struts:struts2-velocity-tools-jsp-jakarta:7.0.0-M8
|    |              \--- org.apache.velocity.tools:velocity-tools-generic:3.1
|    |                   +--- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:2.3 (*)
|    |                   +--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4
|    |                   |    \--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2.2
|    |                   +--- org.apache.commons:commons-digester3:3.2
|    |                   |    \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.8.3 -> 1.9.4 (*)
|    |                   +--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.10 -> 3.14.0
|    |                   +--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30 -> 2.0.13
|    |                   \--- com.github.cliftonlabs:json-simple:3.0.2
|    +--- org.apache.struts:struts-annotations:1.0.8 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.struts:struts2-core:6.4.0 -> 7.0.0-M8 (*)
|    +--- org.apache.struts:struts2-velocity-plugin:6.4.0 -> 7.0.0-M8 (*)
|    \--- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:1.9.4 (*)
+--- org.apache.struts:struts2-json-plugin:7.0.0-M8
+--- org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:7.0.0-M8
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.0.13 -> 6.1.10 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.0.13 -> 6.1.11 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-context:6.0.13 -> 6.1.10 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.13 -> 6.1.10 (*)
+--- org.apache.struts:struts2-config-browser-plugin:7.0.0-M8
|    \--- org.apache.struts:struts2-velocity-plugin:7.0.0-M8 (*)
+--- commons-net:commons-net:3.11.1
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0
+--- org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.12.0 (*)
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0
|    \--- com.google.errorprone:error_prone_annotations:2.27.0
+--- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.78.1
+--- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.20
|    \--- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:1.2.2
|         \--- xmlpull:xmlpull:1.1.3.1
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:3.3.1
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:3.3.1 (*)
|    +--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11
|    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:6.1.11 -> 6.1.10 (*)
|    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.11 (*)
|    \--- org.springframework:spring-websocket:6.1.10 -> 6.1.11
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-context:6.1.11 -> 6.1.10 (*)
|         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:6.1.11 (*)
|         \--- org.springframework:spring-web:6.1.11 -> 6.1.10 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-websocket:6.1.11 (*)
+--- org.springframework:spring-messaging:6.1.11 (*)
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.30

Here the Stacktrace:
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.ConfigurationException: Caught Exception while registering Interceptor class org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:97) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildInterceptor(ObjectFactory.java:210) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.InterceptorBuilder.constructInterceptorReference(InterceptorBuilder.java:73) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlDocConfigurationProvider.lookupInterceptorReference(XmlDocConfigurationProvider.java:1005) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at 
            
            ..........
            
              com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultInterceptorFactory.buildInterceptor(DefaultInterceptorFactory.java:65) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            ... 68 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:161) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:53) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ParameterInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:461) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getParameters(ContainerImpl.java:475) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:302) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            ... 78 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:492) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.lambda$inject$3(ContainerImpl.java:526) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:567) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:526) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:50) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:159) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            ... 82 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:304) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.construct(ContainerImpl.java:435) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:490) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            ... 87 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:118) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580) ~[na:na]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$MethodInjector.inject(ContainerImpl.java:302) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            ... 89 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3601) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2686) ~[na:na]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.addInjectors(ContainerImpl.java:101) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:82) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$1.create(ContainerImpl.java:78) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:123) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$ConstructorInjector.<init>(ContainerImpl.java:357) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$2.create(ContainerImpl.java:312) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl$2.create(ContainerImpl.java:309) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache$CallableCreate.call(ReferenceCache.java:155) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317) ~[na:na]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.internalCreate(ReferenceCache.java:79) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.util.ReferenceCache.get(ReferenceCache.java:123) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getConstructor(ContainerImpl.java:580) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:489) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.lambda$inject$3(ContainerImpl.java:526) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:567) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.inject(ContainerImpl.java:526) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.impl.LocatableFactory.create(LocatableFactory.java:50) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerBuilder$4.create(ContainerBuilder.java:159) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.Scope$2$1.create(Scope.java:53) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:503) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.lambda$getInstance$4(ContainerImpl.java:531) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.callInContext(ContainerImpl.java:567) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at com.opensymphony.xwork2.inject.ContainerImpl.getInstance(ContainerImpl.java:531) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager.setContainer(FreemarkerManager.java:235) ~[struts2-core-7.0.0-M8.jar:7.0.0-M8]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103) ~[na:na]
            ... 91 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
            at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525) ~[na:na]
            ... 122 common frames omitted

gradle file:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
    }
}


plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version "${springBootVersion}"
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.6'
    id 'com.github.andygoossens.modernizer' version "${modernizerPluginVersion}"
    id 'io.freefair.lombok' version "8.6"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/staging/"
    }
}

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'org.ow2.asm:asm:9.7'
    }
    exclude group:"commons-logging", module:"commons-logging"
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(22)
    }
}

if (project.hasProperty("prod") || project.hasProperty("gae")) {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_prod.gradle"
} else {
    apply from: "gradle/profile_dev.gradle"
}

group = "de.tas.cofusim.app"
version = "5.3.1-SNAPSHOT"
//version = "5.3.0-RC"
//version = "5.3.0"

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.ow2.asm:asm:9.7'

    compileOnly 'jakarta.servlet:jakarta.servlet-api:6.1.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.el:jakarta.el-api:6.0.0'
    implementation 'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.2'
    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:4.0.5'
    implementation 'jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:2.1.3'

    // Spring Boot & Framework
    compileOnly "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-core:${springFrameWork}"
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:${springBootVersion}"

    // JSP  and jasper for embedded tomcat
    implementation 'org.glassfish.web:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:3.0.1'
    implementation 'jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl:jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api:3.0.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:10.1.25'

    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:2.23.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:2.23.1'

    // Apache Struts
    implementation "org.apache.struts:struts2-core:${strutsVersion}"
    implementation 'com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-tree-plugin:5.0.4'
    implementation "org.apache.struts:struts2-json-plugin:${strutsVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.struts:struts2-spring-plugin:${strutsVersion}"
    implementation "org.apache.struts:struts2-config-browser-plugin:${strutsVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.apache.struts:struts2-junit-plugin:${strutsVersion}"

    implementation 'commons-net:commons-net:3.11.1'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.14.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-text:1.12.0'

    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.11.0'

    implementation 'org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk18on:1.78.1'

    implementation 'com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:1.4.20'

    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:${springBootVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:${springBootVersion}"
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-inline:5.2.0'

    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket:${springBootVersion}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-websocket:${springFrameWork}"
    implementation "org.springframework:spring-messaging:${springFrameWork}"
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "de.tas.cofusim.webapp.CoFuSimApp"
}

defaultTasks "bootRun"

bootRun
{
    enableAssertions = true
}

compileJava.options.encoding = "UTF-8"

compileTestJava {
    options.encoding = "UTF-8"
    options.compilerArgs.add("-Xlint:deprecation")
}

test {

    useJUnitPlatform()
    exclude "**/*IT*", "**/*IntTest*"
    testLogging {
        events 'FAILED', 'SKIPPED'
    }

    reports.html.required = true
}

gradle.properties:
springBootVersion=3.3.1
springFrameWork=6.1.11
strutsVersion=7.0.0-M8

modernizerPluginVersion=1.9.2
profile=dev


Please include code, not images of code: see Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question. Edit the question and include code fragments.

@j-asgarov I changed my input as requested. I used images because of the character limit. Sorry for the inconvenience I made.

you are using some kind of old dependency in pom that doesn't work with the modern version of spring boot which relies on modern servlet specification using jakarta. Update all your dependencies and if problem persists, add your pom.xml to the question

@j-asgarov can you tell me which dependency? I already cleaned them up. You need to tell me which of them is old.

Like I said - check every single dependency in your pom.xml and make sure each of them is among the latest versions. If that doesn't help add your pom.xml to the question

@j-asgarov Added my gradle file.

You have dependency on struts2-jquery-tree-plugin.
    implementation 'com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery:struts2-jquery-tree-plugin:5.0.4'


It is still not compatible with Struts 7. See the issue Support of Struts 7 #470.

Thank you this was the problem. In my scan via Gradle dependencies this didn't pop up and I went through several plugins. But this was the culprit.

When Struts 7 will be released, then they will support for Jakarta EE spec. Also if you use third party plugins with Struts then read the plugins' release notes and better the source code in the repository :)
